# Factory_girls and ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, tdd, factory-bot

im have model Category.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry :cache_depth => true, :depth_cache_column => :depth
end
```

Category have field name. Im want to build a factory for category with depth level 2.
When this factory will be invoked it must build category level 2 and have parent category with level 1.
How to do this?
Im trying various tricks, all dont work. Im stop at something like that

```
Factory.define :category do |f|
  f.name                        { Faker::Lorem.word }
  f.parent                      { Factory.create(:category) }
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can create another factory, which has no parent.
And if you want to have you're 2 level category you do:

```
Factory(:category_level2)
```

The factory definition could be something like that:

```
Factory.define :category do |f|
  f.name   { Faker::Lorem.word }
end

Factory.define :category_level2, :parent => :category do |f|
  f.parent { Factory.create(:category) }
end
```

Cheers

Comment: strange, im tried this method before and its doesnt work. Now its work. Thanks! I will edit you answer a lil, there is syntax mistakes.

Comment: New syntax
`FactoryGirl.define do
       factory :category do
    name   { Faker::Lorem.word }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category_level2, parent: :category do
    parent { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
  end
end
`